# how to add multiple values in a single session in mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am new to php and mysql. I want to insert multiple values in a single session in mysql and php, but it didn't work out. Below is my code

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['sessionname']['value1']['value2']['value3'])) {
    header("Location:index.php?page=admin");
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO table(value1, value2, value3) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconnect,$_SESSION['sessionname']['value1']['value2']['value3'])."')";
$qry = mysqli_query($dbconnect,$sql);
unset($_SESSION['sessionname']['value1']['value2']['value3']);`
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get an error? Nothing saved? The wrong thing? Does your query work when you edit it out and run it directly in the database? Do you check the return value from your query? Does the database put anything in `mysqli_error`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are trying to insert a single value from your PHP SESSION into 3 columns in your MYSQL table.

```
 $_SESSION['sessionname']['value1']['value2']['value3']` is an associative array.  That statement does not reference 3 separate values, but a single nested value.  Here's a little visualization.

$_SESSION
   -> sessionname
     -> value1
        -> value2
           -> value3
```

But I think you're intending to grab.

```
 $_SESSION
   -> sessionname
      -> value, value2, value3
```

If so, what you need to do is:

```
`$sql = "INSERT INTO table(value1, value2, value3) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconnect,$_SESSION['sessionname']['value1']) . "," . mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconnect,$_SESSION['sessionname']['value2']) . "," . mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconnect,$_SESSION['sessionname']['value3']) ."')";`
```

Apologies for any syntax errors, as HTML textarea's are not my preferred editor :).

Comment: thanks for the help! But where should I put more values inside the session?if(!isset($_SESSION['sessionname']['value1']['value2']['value3'])) {
    header("Location:index.php?page=admin");
} or if(!isset($_SESSION['sessionname']['value1']) &&!isset($_SESSION['sessionname']['value2'])) {
    header("Location:index.php?page=admin");
}

Answer (score 0):

[$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/it/reserved.variables.session.php) can be used as an associative array. You can push your data into your `$_SESSION` variable.

**Remember** to use [session_start](http://php.net/manual/it/function.session-start.php) function every time you need to access your session' data

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['db_data'] = array('value1', 'value2', 'valuex');

$value1 = $_SESSION['db_data']['value1'];
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question; at least in part, that's because the question isn't clear. But the user is already using `$_SESSION` as an associative array.

Comment: I think he is using it in an unappropriate way, he does not show the code, when he set the sessions variables